# Rails - display notification when socket protocol not supported by browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sockets, actioncable

I would like to check if the current browser supports sockets, so my ActionCable can connect. However, I can't find anywhere to put in the logic to render a view if sockets are not supported by the current browser.

I see that the /cable call is called automatically when the browser supports sockets, but if it doesn't, there's no call.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to StackOverflow. This might be as simple as seeing if WebSocket is defined on window. Effectively:

```
if(window.WebSocket) { 
  // your code here.
} else { 
  alert("Websockets is not supported");
}
```

Comment: I added this to my application.js but i get the alert both when there is and isnt socket support in browser O.o

Comment: condition is wrong, it should be if(!window.WebSocket)